# How to Add a macro variable list as a column to a SAS dataset

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a macro variable, `Nums`, which has a list of values i.e  `101, 102, 103, 104, 105`. I have a SAS dataset which has various columns, one of which is a date column. I need to add the `Nums` macro variable to this SAS dataset as a column. Below is the code I have used to generate a macro variable list. Not sure how to proceed further.

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT ID
INTO IDs seperated by ',' FROM Datatable; 
QUIT;
```

Comment: Why move the data into a macro variable if you already have it in a dataset?

Comment: What does the fact that there is a DATE variable have to do with the question?

Comment: For your example what should happen if the target data set has a row count other than 5? If < 5 should the result have 5 rows? If > 5, should the rows > 5 have missing values in the new column, or should the 5 values repeat as needed?  Do you want 5 new columns ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a DO statement.

So if you have macro variable NUMS with value like:

```
%let nums=101,102,103,104,105 ;
```

Then you can use it to generate part of a DO statement.  Inside the DO loop you can set the old dataset.  Make sure to OUTPUT the observations since you are writing more than one observation per iteration of the data step.

```
data want;
  do id=&nums ;
    set have;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

But if you have the data in a dataset already there is no need to first convert the numbers into strings so that they can be stored in a macro variable.

```
data want;
  set have;
  set datatable (keep=id) ;
run;
```

Comment: So I have already generated a macro variable which has a list of values :  &num =101,102,103,104,105;   I have a dataset "have" as you mentioned which has a column date. So I want to create a new column in the dataset have based on a date condition like. If date between 01jan2021 and 31jan2021 then it should hold the value 101 from the macro list

Comment: That is a different question and we would need you to provide more details to be able to suggest a solution. If you want to generate a new value based on whether a number (like a date) is between two other numbers then you probably want a FORMAT and not a  macro variable.